# Django: Return 'None' from OneToOneField if related object doesn't exist?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got a Django class like this:

```
class Breakfast(m.Model):
    # egg = m.OneToOneField(Egg)
    ...

class Egg(m.Model):
    breakfast = m.OneToOneField(Breakfast, related_name="egg")
```

Is it possible to have `breakfast.egg == None` if there is no `Egg` related to the `Breakfast`?

**Edit**: Forgot to mention: I'd rather not change the `related_name` to something like `related_name="_egg"`, then have something like:

```
@property
def egg(self):
    try:
        return self.egg
    except ...:
        return None
```

Because I use the name `egg` in queries, and I'd rather not have to change the queries to using `_egg`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This custom django field will do exactly what you want:

```
class SingleRelatedObjectDescriptorReturnsNone(SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor):
    def __get__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super(SingleRelatedObjectDescriptorReturnsNone, self).__get__(*args, **kwargs)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None

class OneToOneOrNoneField(models.OneToOneField):
    """A OneToOneField that returns None if the related object doesn't exist"""
    related_accessor_class = SingleRelatedObjectDescriptorReturnsNone
```

To use it:

```
class Breakfast(models.Model):
    pass
    # other fields

class Egg(m.Model):
    breakfast = OneToOneOrNoneField(Breakfast, related_name="egg")

breakfast = Breakfast()
assert breakfast.egg == None
```

Comment: Awesome! BTW in 1.10 interfaces are little changed. 
SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor is now ReverseOneToOneDescriptor and ```__get__``` parameters are (self, instance, cls=None)

Answer (score 9):

I just ran into this problem, and found an odd solution to it: if you select_related(), then the attribute will be None if no related row exists, instead of raising an error.

```
>>> print Breakfast.objects.get(pk=1).egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
DoesNotExist: Egg matching query does not exist

>>> print Breakfast.objects.select_related("egg").get(pk=1).egg
None
```

I have no idea if this can be considered a stable feature though.

Answer (score 5):

I know that on ForeignKey you can have `null=True` when you want to allow the model not to point to any other model. OneToOne is only a special case of a ForeignKey:

```
class Place(models.Model)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
class Shop(models.Model)
    place = models.OneToOneField(Place, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

>>>s1 = Shop.objects.create(name='Shop', website='shop.com')
>>>print s1.place
None
```

Comment: This isn't quite my problem, though… I want every `Egg` to belong to a `Breakfast`, but not every `Breakfast` necessarily has an `Egg`.

Comment: And if you move the `OneToOneField` to `Breakfast` with `null=True` doesn't this give you what you need? I think in that case `breakfast.egg` can be `None`, but `egg.breakfast` will throw `DoesNotExists` if it can't find it.

Comment: Not exactly: having the `OneToOne` field on `Breakfast` will put the row on the `Breakfast` table, which is (for various reasons) not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Django 1.10 solution as by Fedor at accepted answer:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.db.models.fields.related import OneToOneField
from django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors import ReverseOneToOneDescriptor

class ReverseOneToOneOrNoneDescriptor(ReverseOneToOneDescriptor):
    def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
        try:
            return super(ReverseOneToOneOrNoneDescriptor, self).__get__(instance=instance, cls=cls)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None

class OneToOneOrNoneField(OneToOneField):
    """A OneToOneField that returns None if the related object doesn't exist"""
    related_accessor_class = ReverseOneToOneOrNoneDescriptor
```

Answer (score 1):

OmerGertel did already point out the `null` option. However, if I understand your logical model right, then what you actually need is a *unique and nullable* foreign key from Breakfast to Egg. So a breakfast may or may not have an egg, and a particular egg can only be associated with one breakfast.

I used this model:

```
class Egg(models.Model):
    quality = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.quality

class Breakfast(models.Model):
    dish = models.TextField()
    egg = models.ForeignKey(Egg, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.dish[:30]
```

and this admin definition:

```
class EggAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

class BreakfastAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Egg, EggAdmin)
admin.site.register(Breakfast, BreakfastAdmin)
```

Then I could create and assign an egg in the edit page for a breakfast, or just do not assign one. In the latter case, the egg property of the breakfast was None. A particular egg already assigned to some breakfast could not be selected for another one.

**EDIT:**

As OmerGertel already said in his comment, you could alternatively write this:

```
    egg = models.OneToOneField(Egg, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: That would mostly work… But, as with Omer's suggestion: it puts the `egg` column in the `Breakfast` table, which (for various reasons) makes life more complex in other ways. Thanks for the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `try` / `except Egg.DoesNotExist` whenever you need to access `Breakfast.egg`; doing so makes it very clear what's going on for people reading your code, and this is the [canonical way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) of handling nonexistent records in Django.

If you really want to avoid cluttering your code with `try` / `except`s, you *could* define a `get_egg` method on `Breakfast` like so:

```
def get_egg(self):
    """ Fetches the egg associated with this `Breakfast`.

    Returns `None` if no egg is found.
    """
    try:
        return self.egg
    except Egg.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

This will make it clearer to people reading your code that eggs are derived, and it may hint at the fact that a lookup gets performed when one calls `Breakfast.get_egg()`.

Personally, I'd go for the former approach in order to keep things as clear as possible, but I could see why one may be inclined to use the latter approach instead.