# Make reverse OneToOneField return None in django

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a django app with the following model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...
```

And I've added a new model which has a OneToOne relationship with A, like so:

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A)
```

As you can see, not every instance of A should have a relationship with B. However, when I try to query A for the existence of a related B model, like:

```
instanceOfA.b
```

I get:

```
DoesNotExist: B matching query does not exist.
```

Is there a way I can make this query return `None` without adding a property to my A model. I'm aware of [this almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955093/django-return-none-from-onetoonefield-if-related-object-doesnt-exist) but sadly it's got no accepted answer and the existing ones suggest modifying A.

I'm currently using:

```
 if hasattr(instanceOfA, b):
        ...
```

But it doesn't feel very clean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: Return 'None' from OneToOneField if related object doesn't exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955093/django-return-none-from-onetoonefield-if-related-object-doesnt-exist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set a method on A, e.g.

```
class A(object):
   # default stuff

   def get_b(self):
       return getattr(self, 'b', None)
```

Or more explicit

```
class A(object):
    def get_b(self):
        try:
            return self.b
        except Foobar.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

This is covered by a Django feature ticket [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10227)

Comment: Oh, wasn't aware of the that feature request. So it seems there's no "clean" way to do this right now. Thanks for the link. BTW, I had tried something similar to your first snippet and got the same exception. For now testing first with hasattr seems to do the trick, since it appears to catch that exception.